# No internet access for wifi connection in my flutter app?

Tags: flutter, wifi

I am using wifi_iot plug-in to establish a wifi connection in a flutter application. I established the connection.But there is no internet access.I need the internet access for the app.

Below is my code.

```
  Future<bool> connectToInternetCableWifi(String ssid, String password,
    {withInternet: true}) async {
  await WiFiForIoTPlugin.connect(ssid,
      password: password,
      joinOnce: false,
      security: STA_DEFAULT_SECURITY,
      withInternet: withInternet);
  await WiFiForIoTPlugin.forceWifiUsage(true);
  return true;
}
```

Note: My app is run on Kiosk mode.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is happening because the `forceWifiUsage(true)` option.

When you do this, the mobile device will attempt to connect to the internet trhough the iot device. Unless the iot device has internet connection, be sure to disable wifi usage:

```
WiFiForIoTPlugin.forceWifiUsage(false);
```